# What is correct, "in the British Islands" or "on the British Islands"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

What is correct, "in the British Islands" or "on the British Islands"? Is there a general rule?

Answer (score 1):

Context, context, context!  It depends on what sort of sentence you're writing; we might say "There are many countries in the British Islands" but also "On one of the British Islands there is a mountain called Pillar." We cannot possibly give a general, all-encompassing rule for this, though given a sentence we could instruct on which is correct. To decide which applies in a given context, you might consider whether the object in your sentence would most likely be described as *on* or *in* something else; a mountain rests *on* top of land, while a country is one of many *in* the group of Islands. But this is perhaps a difficult determination to make for a non-native speaker. If given a sentence as an example of your confusion, perhaps more instructive assistance could be provided.

Answer (score 0):

When speaking of territory, the general rule is to use the preposition "in" rather than "on". As the "British Islands" is a term that refers to a group of states, "in" would be used instead, i.e. "in the British Islands".

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan mentioned, you should use the word *in*, rather than *on*. Another point is that people don't normally say "British Islands", the normal term is *British Isles*.

The British Isles is a geographic term covering the UK, Republic of Ireland and the Isle of Man which is a British overseas territory.