# verb TO BE and prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Is the sentence ''I was in Thassos for my holiday'' grammatically correct? is the preposition for place correct or shall it be ON Thassos?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["In", "at", or "on" an island](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8835/in-at-or-on-an-island)

Answer (score 1):

If Thassos is an island, "on". If it's a political area, e.g., county, city, duchy, then use "in".

What if Θάσος is *both* the name of an island *and also* the name of it's main city? The choice is up to you, depending on context, e.g.,

```
Yesterday we landed on Θάσος and stayed in Θάσος overnight.
```

That choice of prepositions makes clear the difference between island and city.